# Pre-requisites for learning CRM Dynamics

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am not sure if this is a valid question here but couldn't find an answer elsewhere. I am just about to starting training on Microsoft Dynamics CRM and with just over an year of experience with asp.net, a little bit of JavaScript, HTML and CSS, I am not sure if I am headed the right way.

Is this sufficient? What skills should I try to sharpen up before starting with Dynamics?

Comment: The question feels off-topic and a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com since it's about training

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamics CRM is probably the most flexible system I have ever worked on. You can extend it and make it do just about anything. So the first thing you will want to learn about is the different vectors or customization. You can customize CRM in several different ways and each has it merits and drawbacks:

- Javascript [Client side only]. Note that CRM doesn't support customization by directly accessing the DOM, rather you work through XRM exposed interfaces. It allows practical GUI and data manipulation though through REST and FetchXML queries.
- Workflows. These are rules you can program via the "point and click" interface. It allows you to monitor when certain actions happen and then react accordingly. These run server side so it is independent of the client. The system ships with lots of rules, but custom rules can be written to extend these almost infinitely.
- Plugins. Similar to workflows but these fire immediately after subscribed to events. You can do things here like perform validation (which you can also do in Javascript, but plugins are server side) and manipulate data on or after saves.

For custom workflows and plugins, you will definitely need to be familiar with .NET (at least 4.0). You can use either C# or VB.NET, but the Visual Studio integration (which is *really* nice) is limited to C#. You can use VB.NET but it requires a lot of manual configuration so I wouldn't recommend it given the choice between the two. At the time of this writing, however, the Visual Studio integration is limited to VS 2010 and VS 2012 Professional.

This is just a primer, there is lots more info on MSDN and there are tons of blogs available to help you get started. Of course you can always post your specific questions here on SO for help...

Good luck to you.